# Inflated Estimates in Generalized Linear Mixed Models

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, odds-ratio, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I have data containing 40,000 observations, coming from around 30,000 subjects. Most subjects contribute one observation, some contribute two.

The dependent variable is binary (1/0), and let's say, for the sake of the discussion, that I only have one independent variable, also binary. I want to model the effect of X on Y, and to get an odds ratio.

I started by calculating the odds ratio by a simple 2X2 table, and got a **crude OR of 3.18**. Since there is dependency between some observations, I ran the 2X2 analysis for the first observation of the subjects and then for the second, separately, and got OR1 = 3.09 and OR2 = 4.36. **The Mantel Haenszel is OR_m-h = 3.11**. However, when I run a **mixed effects logistic regression**, I get higher OR's. Using the **Laplace approximation, I get an OR of ~4.5**. If I use the **quadrature method of integration, I get an OR of over 6.**

This makes no sense to me. Can someone please explain to me how can this be possible? My random effect (subjectID) has thousands of levels...

My R code of the model is:

```
glmer(Y ~ X + (1 | SubjectID), data = dataset, family = binomial, control =  glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 1)
```

Comment: Don't know exactly what is happening, but lme4 has some niggles in there. I would try R package [glmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmm/index.html).

Comment: Check out for example this thread http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86309/marginal-model-versus-random-effects-model-how-to-choose-between-them-an-advi.  The odds ratio in your glmm applies conditional on a particular value of the random effect.  If you look at the marginal model (integrating out the random effect) the odds ratio will match that computed from your 2x2 table.

Comment: I tried it with SAS (Glimmix) and Stata too. Same results.