# How to test differences of three categories within the same individuals?

Tags: regression, anova, panel-data

Suppose I can observe $Y_{ijt}$,  $i = 1,2,..., n$ , $j  = 1,2,3$ and $t = $ 3 weeks, 1 months, half a year and one year.

I am interested in whether

1. $E(Y|j=1,k) = E(Y|j = 2,k)= E(Y|j=3,k)$
2. $E(Y|j, k) = \alpha_j + \beta_j k $

At first, I thought it was a simple question that I can simply use ANOVA for different periods of time in the first case, and for the second I can run simple linear regression at given $j = 1,2,3$. Yet I realized that for each individual $i$ at given time period $t = k$, $Y_{i1k}$, $Y_{i2k}$ , $Y_{i3k}$ are likely correlated, which render ANOVA ineffective. I am what kind of model should I build to tackle these two questions that I want to tackle?

Answer (score 0):

You can account for the covariance between time periods by using multilevel modeling. Marginal models directly model the [population mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86309/marginal-model-versus-random-effects-model-how-to-choose-between-them-an-adviv), so they may be most useful for you in this question of interest.

You could fit a marginal model such as this one (I'm assuming you meant t when typing k) and conduct the appropriate tests on coefficients.

$E(Y) = \beta_1 + \beta_2 I(j = 2) + \beta_3 I(j = 3) + \beta_4 t + \beta_5 I(j = 2) t + \beta_6 I(j = 3)t$

Marginal models can be fit using the nlme package (or gee for non-identity link functions) in R or PROC MIXED (PROC GENMOD for non-identity link functions) in SAS.

Comment: Hi, thx for the suggestion. The covariance not only exists between different time periods but also exists between different levels... for each individuals will have three different $y_{ij}$ corresponding to $j=1,2,3$, I don't think this model will be able to taken into account this unless I was mistaken something?